# How to use Google Cloud Storage PHP SDK locally, inside CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am developing an application for Google App Engine and I am using the App Engine Launcher to test it locally.

I am trying to figure out how to make use of the Cloud Storage Tools PHP SDK, but I'm struggling when it comes to the PHP "use" function.

When deployed, I can simply use:

```
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
```

As GAE automatically loads the SDK. But locally, it doesnt load it automatically, and I need to do a require_once for the actual PHP file:

```
require_once('E:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools.php');
```

Even with this done, it doesn't work. I'm guessing because I'm not working in the SDK folder (and I shouldn't really have to!).

So how do I et the SDK to load properly so I can use it locally? I'm guessing I just need to change the "use" line, but I'm not sure what to, as I can't seem to specify the ocation exactly, as with the require_once.

Comment: Try with path with no spaces (e.g. Cloud_SDK).

Comment: Well it turns out GAE Launcher does include the SDK, but it uses an emulated storage system. I need to figure out how to view thie emulation and how to create a new bucket, seeing as it won't have the same buckets i have in my actual GCS account

Comment: You do not need to create buckets manually with the local emulation. It does it for you automatically on the first write.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to be doing that for me. Where can I see the local emulation?

Comment: I knew I wasn't going mad, it seems App Engine Launcher 1.9.18 broke GCS locally.